# Magento get the highest price per category

Tags: php, magento

I have Magento enterprise 1.12. and i am looking to add the highest price in the main menu for each category.

I have the following code but it return the highest price in the hole store and i need to pass the category id to this function.

```
$max = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer_filter_price');
$max_price = $max->getMaxPriceInt()+1;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can set the category with `$max->getLayer()->setCurrentCategory(123);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello check below code may be help you

```
<?php echo $maxPrice=Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')
->setCurrentCategory(Mage::registry('current_category'))
->getProductCollection()
->getMaxPrice(); ?>
```